# Passing values from a web page to your app - Android / Blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry

Just wondering if the following is possible:

(A) App loads a login page hosted on remote server using webview (Android) / browserfield (BBerry)
(B) Authentication takes place at the web page housed in webview / browserfield
(C) After successful login - some params are passed back from the webpage and used in subsequent screens in the app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for blackberry

1. Write a Javascript function in your html page which will pass data after login.

//sample code in html.

```
function passData() {
            makeblackberry.pass('Hello','1234');
        }

// in blackberry class
_browserField.extendScriptEngine("makeblackberry.pass",
                    new ScriptableFunction() {
                public Object invoke(Object thiz,final Object[] args)
                {
                              // here args will give you params passed by javascript                       
                              //function
                              // args[0] = Hello and args[1] = 1234
                              //TODO do your task here...

                      return thiz;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

on android:

You can expose javascript interfaces on your webview. This allows you to define a callback in java and call it from the page loaded after the user logged in.

Flow:

1. create your interface with `addJavascriptInterface` [1]
2. app opens webview
3. user logs in
4. webserver returns a page with js calling your exposed interface passing the variables/values you want
5. application continues

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)